# Which linux distro is good as a VPS in parallels?

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, parallels

I will use Parallels Virtuozzo Containers for virtualization and have a good server machine. Which linux distro is good to use?

I have CentOS 5, Debian 5.0 Lenny and Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx.

Comment: You need to edit your question and tell us something about **what you plan to do** with your vps machines. Your question as it stands now is not really answerable.

Comment: Flag this when/if you edit it to be less subjective and we can reopen it. Otherwise you're just going to get answers like "The best is CentOS"

Answer (score 0):

The best is CentOS, I use it for all my clients. Good luck.